# Catching Mysqli Errors

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, mysqli

I have a custom error handler defined, which catches all exceptions and saves them to a log. Right now, if I have a syntax error in a mysqli query, such as a typo, the page completely stops loading at that point. No exception is thrown, so therefore the error handler isn't triggered and nothing is logged.

Is this normal?  Is there a PHP setting that I should check to fix this so that any mysqli query errors throw exceptions?

(I don't want an exception thrown if a query returns 0 results - only if it errors out due to a typo or other error in the query structure)

Example query:

```
if($result=$db->query('SELECT bad_field_reference FROM table')){while($r=$result->fetch_assoc()){$data[]=$r;}}$result->free();
```

If I try to execute this query in PHPMyAdmin it will tell me that column bad_field_reference does not exist. If I try to execute it as part of my PHP script, the entire page stops loading at that point.

**To clarify** I was just doing some testing by looking at the page source. Apparently the rest of the page does load - however, when java is enabled certain items are hidden, then I use jquery to redisplay some content in an animated fashion. Those jquery scripts are not running, so the page appears to have stopped loading.

So - 2 questions now - how do I get PHP to 'catch' the error, and how do I get jquery to still run it's scripts?

Comment: if a failing mysqli query is causing your whole script to stop, and your error handler isnt finishing more than likely your error handler is itself erroring out.

Comment: It's working for every other error / exception that arises - just not if there is an error in the query itself

Comment: show the code you are using for your query

Comment: The queries vary.  Added an example above.

Comment: any errors in your server error log?

Comment: There aren't any errors that are being reported through the custom error handler or exception handler.  I also checked the server error log - don't see any related errors there either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this normal?

No.

> Is there a PHP setting that I should check to fix this so that any mysqli query errors throw exceptions?

Yes.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

However, not all the mysqli_* functions would raise a DB error, some of them raise regular PHP errors, like `free()` does, and this part makes me wonder even more: I am also extremely curious, why do you handle exceptions only but leave PHP errors unhandled. Don't tell me you `have error_reporting(0);` - do you? If so - I've no words.

Finally, I have suspicion that you have raw mysqli->query() scattered all over the code. Which means

- you are using no placeholders to build your queries - making SQL injection inevitable.
- your code is bloated and unreadable

You have to use an abstraction library that will put **all the repeated code** into class methods. See your query run with [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql):

```
$data = $db->getAll('SELECT bad_field_reference FROM table');
```

*it require no horizontal scrolling* to read it,  it is safe, concise, error-proof and **supports placeholders!**

Comment: There is both an exception handler, and an error handler. Neither are triggering right now if there is an error in the query. Error reporting is set to 2048 - Strict.  By placeholders are you referring to prepared statements? I use them for all inserts / updates, but rarely for select queries as the only inputs are integer values which I can easily sanitize.

Comment: That's one of the grave delusions. Your site is open to injection attacks

Comment: Speaking of error handler - how come you didn't have an error message from `free()` call telling you something "require mysqli statement object but boolean given"?

Comment: I'm not sure why I wasn't getting an error kicked out on free(). If the only inputs are integers, which are sanitized with intval(), where would there be a risk of injection?

Comment: 1. Input never being limited to only one type. 2. SQL injection has nothing to do with "input". 3. It's XXI now yet I find myself explaining the necessity of prepared statements...

Comment: For some reason, if I set mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); the page locks up, but if I just set mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR); it works and generates the error properly.

Comment: Error, not exception. And that "Locks up" again. There is something wrong with your error handling. Make sure you have E_ALL in php.ini and have errors logged

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to the 'locking up' part.  In my code sample, I have the following format:

if(--query--){--do something--}free result.

This works fine when the query is syntactically correct. If the query fails, however, there is no result to free. That is what was erroring and causing the page to appear as if it wasn't loading.  Once I moved the 'free result' within the brackets such as

if(--query--){--do something--  free result}

It worked fine and didn't cause any issues. It still doesn't trigger an exception if the query was wrong, but for now I'm fixing that by creating an quick script after queries such as:

```
if($db->error){handle error}
```